# using find algorithm with a vector of unique pointers

Tags: c++

I have a vector of unique pointers. I'm adding to it using move semantics. Here's the partial class:

```
class execution_collection {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<execution> exec_ptr;
    typedef std::vector<exec_ptr> exec_ptr_vector;
    exec_ptr_vector executions;
    ...
public:
    ...
    double last_buy_fill_price(const std::string &) const;
    ...
};
```

When I try to std::find_if with lambda I get `error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr...`. I don't understand where am I trying to copy the ptr?

```
double execution_collection::last_buy_fill_price(const string &symbol) const {

    auto it = find_if(executions.begin(),executions.end(),
        [&symbol](exec_ptr ptr){
            return ptr->getSymbol() == symbol && ptr->getQuantity() > 0;
        });

    if (it != executions.end()) 
        return it->get()->getPrice();
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take the parameter to your lambda by const ref: `[&symbol](exec_ptr const& ptr){`

Comment: because of this line `[&symbol](exec_ptr ptr){` you can't copy `unique_ptr`, change it to `(const exec_ptr& ptr)`

Comment: that was it, thanks

Comment: `std::find` doesn't take a predicate. Perhaps you mean `find_if`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to copy the unique_ptr which breaks the rules of the unique_ptr. Pass it by reference.

```
[&symbol](const exec_ptr & ptr)
{
    return ptr->getSymbol() == symbol && ptr->getQuantity() > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little template boilerplate we can arguably make the logic at the `find` call a little more readable, such that we can write this:

```
auto i = std::find_if(things.begin(), things.end(),
                      byContents(bySymbolWithQuantity("bar")));
```

Whether you want this is of course a matter of taste.

Here is some code that achieves this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Thing {
    Thing(std::string symbol, int quantity)
            : symbol(std::move(symbol)), quantity(quantity)
    {}

    auto getSymbol() const -> std::string const& { return symbol; }
    auto getQuantity() const -> int { return quantity; }

    std::string symbol;
    int quantity;
};

template<class Symbol>
auto bySymbolWithQuantity(Symbol&& symbol)
{
    return [symbol = std::forward<Symbol>(symbol)](auto&& thing) mutable -> decltype(auto)
    {
        return thing.getSymbol() == symbol and thing.getQuantity() > 0;
    };
}

template<class Pred>
auto byContents(Pred&& pred)
{
    return [pred = std::forward<Pred>(pred)](auto&& ptr, auto&&...args) mutable -> decltype(auto) {
        return pred(*ptr, args...);
    };
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>> things;
    things.push_back(std::make_unique<Thing>("foo", 10));
    things.push_back(std::make_unique<Thing>("bar", 5));


    auto i = std::find_if(things.begin(), things.end(),
                          byContents(bySymbolWithQuantity("bar")));


    std::cout << (**i).getSymbol() << " : " << (**i).getQuantity() << std::endl;
}
```